# package visibility in android 11 kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, android-manifest, android-11

I want to find email client installed on device and redirect email id on that application to send email message. It working fine below on android 10, but it not working in android 11. I found article regarding [Package visibility filtering on Android 11](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility#blog-posts). I didn't understand how to achieve this code functionality in android 11

```
request?.url.toString().startsWith("mailto:") -> {
       val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO)
       intent.type = "message/rfc822"
       intent.data = Uri.parse(request?.url.toString())
        view?.context?.packageManager?.let { packageManager ->
        if (packageManager.resolveActivity(intent, 0) != null) {
            view.context?.startActivity(intent)
        } else {
          Log.E("Error to find ", "Email client")
        }
     }
}
```

It launch email client on lower than **android 10**  but unable to find email client in **android 11**. It shows always **Error to find Email client**. Can someone explain me in more detail how **Package visibility filtering on Android 11** is working and can someone share some piece of code how to achieve this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As your app targets Android 11 or higher and needs to interact with apps other than the ones that are visible automatically, add the **queries** element in your app's manifest file. Within the  element, specify the other apps by package name, by intent signature, or by provider authority.

To view other packages, declare your app's need for increased package visibility using the  element.

```
<manifest...>
     <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/jpeg" />
        </intent>
    </queries>
    <application>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

If your app might need to query or interact with all installed apps on a device (which is rare) the you can opt **QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES** permission introduced in  Android 11.

If resolveActivity() return null then try with [queryIntentActivities()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager#queryIntentActivities(android.content.Intent,%20int))

For more please refer : https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility/declaring

Comment: This answer should be accepted but QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES should be avoided.

Comment: I am not sure but for me, `resolveActivity` works without any problem to find list of apps that serves `Intent.ACTION_VIEW`. I am targeting API `30` as well